# Where (in which class) to collect the information that the user is sending (POST and GET)?

Tags: php, http-post, http-get

I there:

I am designing a common web system using PHP where the user sends information, then the system collects it then i creates the model, apply the logic and such and finally it creates the html result.

I work under SRP, so i create different classes for each work (model, logic, web and such) but i don't know where to collect the information that the user is sending, **i.e. in which class should i put the $_GET and $_POST ?**

a) in the so called "controller" class ?

b) in a facade class?

c) I can't apply in the model (domain) class because while most of the information collected is about the model but other information that the user is sending is out of the scope of the model (such "action", "button" and such).

d) Sends it straights to the ViewModel?.

e) Other.

[image]

Example:

```html
<?php

 include "model/Customer.php";
 include "....."; // other includes.

 $customer=new Customer();
 // where this part: ???
 $customer->idCustomer=$_GET['idCustomer'];
 $customer->name=$_GET['name'];
 // end ???

 $vm=new CustomerVM();
 $vm->customer=$customer;
 // logic here
 $logic=new CustomerLogic();

 // view here
 $view=new CustomerView($vm);
 $view->insertForm();

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you work with MVC pattern.

The controller consolidates and delegetes. So it's right that the controller gets its input from POST/GET/PUT, etc.

Documentation: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ModelViewController